# How do I determine what version of TFS is installed?

Tags: team-foundation-server

I would like to determine whether a server has TFS 2005 or TFS 2008 and whether any service pack has been installed. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

This works much better...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2008/01/15/checking-your-tfs-version-and-extending-trials.aspx

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! We really do prefer that answers have content, not pointers to content. This may theoretically answer the question however, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I see a '403 Forbidden' error on the link now.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you: http://devmatter.blogspot.com/2007/07/how-to-determine-what-version-of-tfs-is.html

Comment: The updated utility is at http://devmatter.blogspot.com/2008/10/tfsinfo-updated-for-tfs-2008-sp1.html but I'm having trouble getting it to work.

Answer (score 0):

On the server, navigate to:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Team Foundation Server\Web Services\Services\bin
```

Right-click on the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll file, and select Properties. Under the Version tab, check the value of Product Version in the list box.